# Is MySQL an in-memory database?

Tags: mysql, in-memory-database, in-memory

Please clarify is MySQL an in-memory database?

Comment: MySQL is *a database*. It uses pluggable storage engines that are configurable in such a way where they *can* use RAM to store data. Please consider removing this question, it's of super low quality and largely useless.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL offers several [storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html) *one of them* is [`MEMORY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html):

> The `MEMORY` storage engine (formerly known as `HEAP`) creates
>   special-purpose tables with contents that are stored in memory.
>   Because the data is vulnerable to crashes, hardware issues, or power
>   outages, only use these tables as temporary work areas or read-only
>   caches for data pulled from other tables.

However, this is a unique distinction. It does not qualify it as in in-memory database. There are other systems that also offer in-memory options; like SQLite.

An example of an in-memory database is [voltdb](http://voltdb.com/).

[redis](http://redis.io) is sometimes referred to as an in-memory database, but strictly speaking, its a key/value store. There are no "tables" as you would be used to in MySQL.